# Каким образом в Linux (xfce) можно получить контекст по выделенному фрагменту?

Tags: linux, библиотеки

Цель — по выделенному слову определить предложение, в котором оно находится.

Пример:

[image]

Как это вообще можно сделать? Лучше всего было бы средствами библиотеки для python или с помощью bash.

Да, выделять слова собираюсь только в браузере google chrome. Возможно у него есть API?

Comment: Где получить, что получить, кому получить - ничего непонятно.

Comment: В Linux есть утилита `xsel`. Она при запуске выводит в консоль текст, находящийся под выделением. В примере выведется: "поддержку". Я хочу узнать, как можно при таком же выделении вывести предложение в красной рамке.

Comment: И еще один пример.
В расширении LinguaLeo это здорово реализовано (правда только в пределах браузера): http://i.imgur.com/ox4UH.png

Comment: xsel запрашивает у X-сервера текущий selection. В том же браузере (более "общо" - в приложении, самом выполнившем selection) как выбрать предложение - это понятно. 

--

Действительно интересно, можно ли (не помню уже деталей X-windows) по selection выйти на окно? Боюсь, что даже если можно, текст в окне не получить.

Comment: Возможно, можно получить весь текст __активного__ окна? Хотя нужное слово может встретиться несколько раз.

Answer (score 1):

не совсем понятны условия, в которых программа должна работать.

поэтому предложу такую «хитрость»:

```
$ xdotool click --clearmodifiers 1 click 1 click 1; xclip -o
```

объяснение:

- `xdotool` производит тройной «щелчок» левой кнопкой мыши (что обычно рассматривается как команда выделить всю строку).
- выделение (обычно) попадает в буфер `XA_PRIMARY`.
- а `xclip` выводит его в `stdout`.